# NSStatusItem left click

Tags: swift, nsstatusitem

First : I'm new with Swift developpement.
I'm using [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/98178/os-x-tutorial-menus-popovers-menu-bar-apps) tutorial to make a popup that will appears when I click on my top bar icon.

So my AppDelehgate code is :

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification){
    print("START !");
    if let button = statusItem.button {
        button.image = NSImage(named: "logo");
        button.action = Selector(("togglePopover:"));
        //button.target = self;
    }

    popover.contentViewController = QuotesViewController(nibName: "QuotesViewController", bundle: nil);
}

func togglePopover(envoyeur: AnyObject?){
    print("TOGGLE !");
    if popover.isShown{
        closePopover(sender: envoyeur)
    } else {
        showPopover(sender: envoyeur)
    }
}
```

But never the "TOGGLE !" text appears, the event doesn't works.
I put the "button.target = self;" into comment because it's crashing if I don't do it. The event seem's to be trigged, but i've got an error :

```
START !
2017-06-08 15:55:29.116275+0200 MyWallpaper[7590:407660] -[MyWallpaper.AppDelegate togglePopover:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x61000002a520
2017-06-08 15:55:29.122570+0200 MyWallpaper[7590:407660] [General] -[MyWallpaper.AppDelegate togglePopover:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x61000002a520
2017-06-08 15:55:29.125822+0200 MyWallpaper[7590:407660] [General] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffb36f32cb __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fffc84fe48d objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffb3774f04 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffb3665755 ___forwarding___ + 1061
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffb36652a8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fffc90153a7 _os_activity_initiate_impl + 53
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fffb18e1721 -[NSApplication(NSResponder) sendAction:to:from:] + 456
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fffb13c5cc4 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 86
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fffb18ceff7 -[NSStatusBarButtonCell _sendActionFrom:] + 155
    9   libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fffc90153a7 _os_activity_initiate_impl + 53
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fffb13c4426 -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 2481
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fffb1408272 -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 798
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fffb18cea1f -[NSStatusBarButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 327
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fffb13c2ddb -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 832
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fffb1a5d24f -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _handleMouseDownEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 6341
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fffb1a59a6c -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 1942
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fffb1a58f0a -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) sendEvent:] + 541
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fffb18d26d1 -[NSStatusBarWindow sendEvent:] + 581
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fffb18dd681 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) sendEvent:] + 1145
    19  AppKit                              0x00007fffb1158427 -[NSApplication run] + 1002
    20  AppKit                              0x00007fffb1122e0e NSApplicationMain + 1237
    21  MyWallpaper                         0x00000001000039ad main + 13
    22  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fffc8de3235 start + 1
    23  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Swift `#selector` syntax

```
button.action = #selector(togglePopover(_:)) // or just #selector(togglePopover)
```

Comment: Thanks, but returns me : Use of unresolved identifier 'togglePopover' :/